# How to make buttons to center align left align etc in tkinter text widget

Tags: python, tkinter

So I am making a GUI like ms word and I added buttons to center align, left align and right align but when I added the functionality and clicked center align, it center-aligned the whole document whereas I was expecting it to center align the selected text is there any possible way to do it.
image of my GUI for better understanding [my gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8eRk.png)

Comment: please provide more detail

Comment: Please show an example of what you tried. You can use tab stops to align images, have you tried that? Have you tried using tags?

Comment: i just resolved it

Comment: @MuhammadJamil well then it would be great if you wrote an answer, it would be pretty sad for a person in the future to come to this question only to find this without an answer

Comment: Actually i am trying to find another better way because it just justify the whole document but I can provide you with the code but it justify the whole document when I posted the answer that was sometimes giving errors but now it's working good and if you got any answers then please share.the code:def align_left():
    text_content = text_editor.get(1.0, 'end')
    text_editor.tag_config('left', justify=tk.LEFT)
    text_editor.delete(1.0, tk.END)
    text_editor.insert(tk.INSERT, text_content, 'left')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer answer is below:
`def center_align(): TextArea.tag_configure("center", justify='center') TextArea.insert("1.0","") TextArea.tag_add("center", "sel.first", "sel.last")`